# Cant find System.Runtime when I add async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure-functions

I'm making an Azure Function, and I need it to do some async work. But I get this strange error it can't load assembly `System.Runtime` once I call a awaited method:

```
[FunctionName("MyTestFunction")]
async public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("testtopic", "testsubscription", AccessRights.Listen, Connection = "MyServiceBusConnection")]
    string mySbMsg,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    client = new DocumentClient(new System.Uri(ENDPOINT), ENDPOINT_KEY);
    await client.CreateDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DATABASE, COLLECTION_ID), string.Format("{ \"newmessage\": {0} }", mySbMsg));

    log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does it continue to happen if you install the NuGet package `System.Runtime`?

Comment: Yes, I have System.Runtime 4.3.0 installed. It wars 4.1.0 but something bugged because I cant downgrade to 4.1.0. I then get "Package restore failed"

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Whats needed to make the function work with await/async? Seems to be the problem. When I try to include SystemThreading.Tasks I get that error message

Comment: Check the exact error message, see what version of `System.Runtime` is being searched for

Comment: Unable to repro this issue. Please provide exact repro steps and also the error message you are seeing.

Comment: By the way, does this code even compile? Shouldn't there be `var client = ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a workaround for this problem - please have a look at this [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-documentdb#output---c-example).

Using Azure Function built-in functionality seems easier and doesn't require you to await anything, which might solve your problem.

Additionally, DocumentClient class is intended to be instantiated once and reused throughout the lifetime of an application. Please have a look at this article - [Improper Instantiation antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/)